# a question on Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()

Tags: java

The following function is used to compute memory usage.

```
private static long getMemoryUse(){
  putOutTheGarbage();
  long totalMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();

   putOutTheGarbage();
   long freeMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();

   return (totalMemory - freeMemory);
 }
```

I do not understand how to understand `Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()`? In specific, how to understand the relationships connecting `Runtime`, `getRuntime()` and `totalMemory()`?

Comment: BTW - Just a WAG but I reckon that the `putOutTheGarbage()` method does not do what it advertises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In specific, how to understand the relationships connecting "Runtime", "getRuntime()" and "totalMemory()"

`Runtime` is a class.

`getRuntime()` is a static method of `Runtime` that returns a (actually THE ONLY) instance of `Runtime`.

`totalMemory()` is an instance method of `Runtime` that returns the "total memory" used.

For more details, read the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html).

Note that the definitions of the values returned by `freeMemory`, `totalMemory` and `maxMemory` are rather vague.  Furthermore, the first two do not return the memory usage at the instant the method is called.  Instead, they typically return a value calculated last time the GC ran.

(One reason for the vaguely worded API specs is to avoid making these methods too costly, and/or too restrictive on the JVM implementation.  It would be a BAD THING if the JVM couldn't use some fast GC technology because of a javadoc requirement to return accurate values for the memory usage at all times.)